# Subdomain-to-folder redirect (HTTPS)

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, apache-2.4

I have the following in my httpd.conf at the very bottom. No other configuration is done.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@contoso.com
    ServerName www.contoso.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stoplight.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.contoso\.com
    RewriteCond /var/www/html/%1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.contoso.com/blarg%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.contoso.com

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stoplight.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.contoso\.com
    RewriteCond /var/www/html/%1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.contoso.com/blarg%{REQUEST_URI}

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile BLAH BLAH BLAH this works great
    SSLCertificateKeyFile BLAH BLAH BLAH this works great
    SSLCertificateChainFile BLAH BLAH BLAH this works great

</VirtualHost>
```

So I have two goals in my redirects: redirect all http to https (working) and redirect 
blarg.contoso.com to contoso.com/blarg (and https if not already).

If I type in http://blarg.contoso.com, I get redirected to https://www.contoso.com/blarg. However, if I type in https://blarg.contoso.com, no redirection occurs.

Any tips? Running RHEL 6.5 64bit. Thanks so much!

EDIT:

Because of the help of you guys, I removed the subdomain redirect from the HTTP virtualhost and moved it to the HTTPS virtualhost. I am only posting the HTTPS one because that is the only one I'm having trouble with.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.summitcreators.com

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stoplight.* [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.summitcreators\.com
    RewriteCond /var/www/html/%1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.summitcreators.com/stoplight%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>
```

Now NO subdomain redirection works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in https section.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` uses the

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stoplight.* [NC]
```

So the only rewriting your SSL vhost does is directed at request to domains that start with `stoplight`.

I suspect that removing that rule will solve your issue.

Comment: He has exact the same rule in his http vhost too. I would suggest first to remove those rewrites from http and only do rewrites in https, and replace the NC with OR on RewriteCond stoplight line.

Comment: I'm going to give these suggestions a try ASAP, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @JakovSosic I made the changes you suggestion but no luck. Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: did you try my latest answer, about turning rewrite on?